# How do I set property to zero

Tags: c#

I need to set a label to zero. It is showing 120. There is a button that will return the required hours for this program. It is a program that returns the required hours for students major. There are 3 forms. bladah bladah yadah yadah. asdfkashdfjkhasjkdhfjkasdjkfajkdjfkajksdfjkakjshdfkjakjsdfjkashdfakjsdf

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Computer_Science_Student
    {
        class CompSciStudent : Student
        {
            // Constants
            private double MATH_HOURS = 20;
            private double CS_HOURS = 40;
            private double GEN_HOURS = 60;

            // Fields
            private string _academicTrack;

            // Constructor
            public CompSciStudent(string name, string id, string track)
               : base(name, id)
            {
                _academicTrack = track;
            }

            // AcademicTrack property
            public string AcademicTrack
            {
                get { return _academicTrack; }
                set { _academicTrack = value; }
            }

            // RequiredHours property
            public override double RequiredHours
            {

                get { return MATH_HOURS + CS_HOURS + GEN_HOURS; }
            }
        }
    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Computer_Science_Student
{
    abstract class Student
    {
        // Fields
        private string _name;
        private string _id;

        // Constructor
        public Student(string name, string id)
        {
            _name = name;
            _id = id;
        }

        // Name property
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        // ID property
        public string ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        // RequiredHours property (abstract)
        public abstract double RequiredHours
        {
            get;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Computer_Science_Student
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Variables to hold input
            string name, id, track;


            // Get the student's name and ID.
            name = nameTextBox.Text;
            id = idTextBox.Text;


            // Get the student's academic track
            if (infoSystemsRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                track = "Information Systems";
            }
            else
            {
                track = "Software Engineering";
            }

            // Create a CompSciStudent object.
            CompSciStudent csStudent =
               new CompSciStudent(name, id, track);

            // Display the student's required hous.
            requiredHoursLabel.Text = 
                csStudent.RequiredHours.ToString("n1");
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Close the form
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where are you setting the labels text? Also `MATH_HOURS + CS_HOURS + GEN_HOURS` does equal 120... what are you expecting? Why not create a const that is 120 since you can't change the output?

Comment: If you're talking about `RequiredHours`, it's a calculated property. The only way you can set it to zero is by setting its components to zero.

Comment: I have other classes. Just need to get the required hours label to be set initially to zero. It is appearing 120 without me clicking a button.

Comment: It will as I explained, please show that code...

Comment: It's because you have 3 variables (incorrectly called "constants" - constants are defined with the `const` keyword - you actually have fields), and you're assigning values to them. `MATH_HOURs = 20`, `CS_HOURS=40`, and `GEN_HOURS = 60`. At the time when you query the value of `RequiredHours`, you sum these three values together. As I said in my previous comment: you have to set these 3 variables to 0 for `RequiredHours` to return 0.

Comment: But I want it to return 120, what I mean is when I run the program the required hours label is already displaying 120 without me clicking on a button to get required hours.

Comment: ...and the button doesn't set those 3 values why? You're in control of your program. If you've set a label to `RequiredHours`, then what do you realistically expect it to display? I expect 120.

Answer (score 0):

In your code class CompSciStudent has the following attributes and methods:

```
// Constants
private double MATH_HOURS = 20;
private double CS_HOURS = 40;
private double GEN_HOURS = 60;

public override double RequiredHours
{
    get { return MATH_HOURS + CS_HOURS + GEN_HOURS; }
}
```

RequiredHours always returns sum of MATH_HOURS + CS_HOURS + GEN_HOURS, which equals 120.
Also as another person pointed out, those are not constants, they are variables. A constant would be:

```
const double MATH_HOURS = 20;
```

Here you're creating a new CompSciStudent object:

```
// Create a CompSciStudent object.
CompSciStudent csStudent = new CompSciStudent(name, id, track);

// Display the student's required hous.
requiredHoursLabel.Text = csStudent.RequiredHours.ToString("n1");
```

In your Form1_Load() method you're setting requiredHoursLabel.Text to csStudent.RequiredHours which is always 120 that's why you're seeing "120" in the text field.

The Form1_Load() method is going to be called after your form loads so it is typically used to initialize the form. So what you're doing right now is to initialize requiredHoursLabel.Text to 120.

If you have some other behavior in mind they you'll need to add something like another button besides "Close" like "OK" or "Save" or something to accept the input the user entered into the form.

Comment: I feel like I am needing to set something in the required hours property.  Or can I set the CompSciStudent object to something else?

Comment: It all depends on what the specs for the assignment are. It would make perfect sense for example to have field that shows the required hours for a particular major in addition to a field that indicates how many course hours have been completed that is an edit field for example.